How can i check if a discord user finished onboarding?
In discord.py 2.0, I do onboarding when a user first enters the server.
I'm curious if there is a d.py 2.0 reference to check whether onboarding was completed properly.
Can I get some reference, API or code that might be helpful?
I searched through references and Googling, but couldn't find it yet.
We need your help
I would appreciate your help

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=onboard

Can I get some example code?

You could use the on_member_update event to check if the MemberFlags from the specified user got changed.
Inside the MemberFlags of a server member is some handy information that can be very helpful - like in your case - to check if the user completed the onboarding process.
As the documentation of discord.py says, completed_onboarding returns a bool value, which makes it very easy to check:
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member):
    # Check if the member has completed onboarding
    if after.flags.completed_onboarding and not before.flags.completed_onboarding:
        print(f"{after.name} has completed onboarding - do something else")

This event provides 2 member objects: the first is an old version and the second is an updated one.
You can check the official documentation out to learn more about MemberFlags:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=onboard#discord.MemberFlags

Um, I need to complete all onboarding print(f"onBoard Complete {member.mention}") Um, how do I fix the code?

@KimHaley i don't really understand what you mean with that.

If you are onboarding, you must complete a total of 3 steps.
So, when user A completes all three stages of onboarding, I want to print(f"{user}")
